# Why does attribute change still cause the @Input to be change in ngDoCheck when change detection is on push?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

Consider this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PACEnm8TLYPXwc9lh1Og?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'my-app-n1',
  template: `
    <my-app-n2 [from2]="from1"></my-app-n2>
    <div>
      {{from1.name}}
      <input type="button" value="n1"  (click)="changen1()">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App2 {

  @Input() from1;

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('do check 1 ', this.from1);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    console.log('n1 change ', changes);
  }  
  changen1() {
    this.from1 = {'name': 'name1-2'}
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-app-n1 [from1]="from"></my-app-n1>
    <input type="button" value="root" (click)="changen0()">
  `,
})
export class App {
  from: any;
  constructor() {
    this.from = {'name': 'name0'}
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    console.log('n0 change ', changes);
  }  

  changen0() {
    this.from.name = 'name-0-2-2'
  }

}
```

Notice that `App2` uses `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

When `changen0` is clicked I expect `ngOnChanges` to not be called (since no new reference is assigned) and `ngDoCheck` to be called with `this.from1` to have the data  `{'name': 'name0'}` and the view still displaying `name0`

But instead

`ngDoCheck` is called with `this.from1` equal  `{'name': 'name-0-2-2'}`

and the view is displaying `name0`

My question is the following

1. Why is the property `this.from1` changed?
2. And if the model is changed why is the view inconsistent with the model?

Comment: it's the same reason as in your [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822276/why-changedetectionstrategy-onpush-does-not-update-in-input-attribute-change-bu/46823249#46823249), do not use native DOM events when testing OnPush, better use `setTimeout` to simulate a change

Comment: its slightly different though, since in this case the view will not be changed, what is the reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: I posted my answer. Let me know if there's something unclear in this or the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` for the `App2` which means that CD will not be triggered for `App2` unless the input binding `[from1]="from"` is updated.

So when you update the `name` property here the `name` is updated:

```
changen0() {
    this.from.name = 'name-0-2-2'
}
```

you don't update the reference to `this.from` and hence change detection is not triggered for the `App2` so you don't see the change in the HTML. `ngOnChanges` is not called as well.

> ngDoCheck is called with this.from1 equal  {'name': 'name-0-2-2'}

`ngDoCheck` doesn't mean your component being checked. It's called when Angular checks the parent component. Read this article for more information:

- [If you think `ngDoCheck` means your component is being checked — read this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5)