# Why changeDetectionStrategy.OnPush does not update in @Input attribute change but does update @Output trigger attribute change?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

Consider this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K1tKdpTm3YZ7T9fETdXs?p=preview)

`Grandchild Component`

```
<button (click)="back2click()"></button>

@Input() from2;
@Output()
back2 = new EventEmitter<any>();

back2click() {
   this.back2.emit('hi');
}
```

`Child Component`

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,

<my-app-n2 [from2]="from1" (back2)="handleback2($event)"></my-app-n2>

@Input() from1;
@Output() back1 = new EventEmitter<any>();

handleback2() {
    this.back1.emit('hi')
}
```

`Parent Component`

```
<my-app-n1 [from1]="from" (back1)="handleback1($event)"></my-app-n1>
handleback1 () {
    this.from.name = 'handline4';
}
```

I see that when `button` is clicked

```
back2click -> emit -> handleback2 -> emit -> handleback1 
    -> attribute is updated -> all child view are updated
```

This is confusing since I expect only the parent view to get updated since `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` is config in child component.

I think I am missing something, can someone point me the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All native events mark the path to the root component for check once. Here in the template of `Grandchild Component` you're using native `click` event:

```
<button (click)="back2click()"></button>
```

Hence the hierarchy of components is marked for the check once.

```
   Root Component -> ViewState.ChecksEnabled = true
     |
    ...
     |
   Parent  -> ViewState.ChecksEnabled = true
     |
     |
   Child  (onPush)  -> ViewState.ChecksEnabled = true
     |
     |
   Grand child (event triggered here) -> markForCheck() -> ViewState.ChecksEnabled = true
```

For the most comprehensive explanation of change detection read:

- [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

To learn more about `markForCheck` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396740/2545680) and read this article:

- [If you think `ngDoCheck` means your component is being checked — read this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5)

Comment: so if the view is changed, why is `ngOnChange` not called? Does `checksEnabled = true ` not call `ngOnChange` ?

Comment: @Jal, these are unrelated. `ngOnChanges` is only called when Angular checks **parent** component **if** the input binding has changed. In your case it hasn't changed. And the view is updated when the **current** component being checked.